# Ajax page return nothing on refresh the page button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I made an ajax function calling php pages from a /pages folder and i call my pages in a `ajax-container` div, but when i click on the `refresh the page` button the history pushstate is working because i see the page in the adress, but it's loading only the content of my index.php but nothing happens in my `ajax-container`.
So how can i get the page i called when i refresh the page?

htacces:

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*).php$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

ajax-container:

```html
<div id="ajax-container">
<?php
$d = "pages/";
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = strtolower($_GET['p']);
    if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/", $p) && file_exists($d . $p . ".php")) {
        include $d . $p . ".php";
    } else {
        include $d . "404.html";
    }
} else {
    include $d . "home.php";
}
?>
</div>
```

and my ajax function:

```js
var afficher = function(data, page) {

    $('#ajax-container').delay(200).fadeOut(250, function() {
        $('#ajax-container').empty();
        $('#ajax-container').append(data);
        $('#ajax-container').fadeIn(100, function() {});

    });
};

var lastRequest = null;
if (lastRequest !== null) {
    lastRequest.abort();
}

var loadPage = function(page, storeHistory) {
    if (typeof storeHistory === 'undefined') {
        storeHistory = true;
    }


    lastRequest = $.ajax({
        url: "pages/" + page,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            afficher(html, page);
            if (storeHistory === true) {
                history.pushState({
                    'key': 'value',
                    'url': page
                }, '', page);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            afficher('erreur lors du chagement de la page');
        }
    });

    return false;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
            if (e.state === null) {
                loadPage('home.php');
            } else {
                loadPage(e['state']['url'], false);
            }
        });
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm rather confused on what you are trying to do, on top of only being familiar with pure javascript ajax. However, "loadPage" looks like you want to go to a new page right? ... AJAX isn't meant to go to a new page, it brings content in without reloading a page.

Comment: yes and what i want to do it's on my index.php i bring 'about.php' in my ajax-container so now in my 'about.php' i have an other link, and i want when i click this link, AJAX replace 'about.php' by this new page

Answer (score 0):

I see, well I don't understand jquery since I've only worked with pure javascript AJAX. However, I do know some things to check.

1-Is your php echoing things out? Even if you get a php file by AJAX, it won't display anything unless the information is being echoed out.

2-I don't see a innerHTML, as with my experience (again only used pure javascript AJAX), the echoed php code would be put in the div's innerHTML. Example with your div:
before ajax:

```
<div id="ajax-container">
    hello
</div>
```

AJAX gets php file:

AJAX finishes and the content is ready... ( xmlhttp=XMLHttpRequest() )

```
document.getElementById("ajax-container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;//responseText= whatever php echoed out
```

after AJAX:

```
<div id="ajax-container">
   hi
</div>
```

This replaces the div's content, the following would add to it:

```
document.getElementById("ajax-container").innerHTML.=xmlhttp.responseText;
                         note the period for concat^
```

3- if you still having problems, open up your browser developer tools->network tab->php file name

This will allow you to see whatever the php file is saying (var_dumps, echos, errors if error reporting stuff allows it)